# Faker issues seeding data on a belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, faker

I have a model `User` which I recently associated with a `Team` model.  But now when I try to seed my database I get a long error that starts with:

```
rake db:seed
rake aborted!
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Team
```

I understand that this can be the result of trying to reassign a superclass after a class is created but I've looked through my project and I don't redeclare the superclass for the `Team.rb`.

This is my seeds.rb

require 'faker'
include Faker

```
5.times do
  User.create!(
    email: Faker::Internet.email,
    name: Faker::Name.first_name,
    password: Faker::Internet.password(8),
    team_id: 1 
  )
end
```

I should note that I'm not using Faker to seed any Teams so `team_id:` should always be one for now.

Team.rb

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
 belongs_to :team
 has_many :user_tasks
 ...
```

From .pry

```
pry(main)> show-source Team

From: /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/faker-1.9.3/lib/faker.rb @ line 40:
Class name: Faker::Base
Number of lines: 210

** Warning: Cannot find code for Oregon chickens. Showing superclass Faker::Base instead. **

class Base
  Numbers = Array(0..9)
  ULetters = Array('A'..'Z')
  Letters = ULetters + Array('a'..'z')
```

Comment: Try to create an `User` using the Rails console. Do you get the same error?

Comment: Can you put a binding.pry in your seed and `show-source Team`? This kind of error is tricky to track down, but you're absolutely right in terms of what causes it. We need to figure out where these classes are being defined.

Comment: Also, just because I'm superstitious, does `bundle exec rake db:seed` yield the same result?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.   A few things, I tried to create a user in the Rails console and it rolled back the transition whenever I tried to save it (this was both with and without the team_id).  But User.all shows that all the users from Faker were added somehow.  `bundle exec rake db:seed` does not work.  Lastly @Stuart I've included the output from .pry in the original question.  Seems like Team is inheriting from Faker?

Comment: Ok, so I think I just made a silly mistake by forgetting to give my User a password when saving in the Rails console because I can save the User with no problem from the console and they associate with a team but same issues with Faker.